# How can I search words starting with capital letter and small letter using preg_grep command...?

Tags: php, regex

I am making a search criterion where it should search for inputted value (at least partial search).
An example is given below.
It searches only for words starting with EXACT match . But I want to make it to search for both caps and smalls...

```
$rr="In";
$matched_list =array('India','Pakistan','Ausis');
$m=preg_grep('/'.$rr.'/', $matched_list);
print_r($m);
```

It searches only for "India" and not for "india"....!!!!

What to do to make it to search for "india" also...?????/

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Very easy, just add a `i` (for case **i**nsensitive) after the closing `/`:

```
$m=preg_grep('/'.$rr.'/i', $matched_list);
```

Also, as a minor note. Your expression `"In"` would also match on "Ch**in**a" and others having the match somewhere in between. If this isn't intended, you'll have to tell it to look at the beginning only:

```
$rr="^In"; // ^ will match the beginning of the string or a line (depending on the settings)
```